# Why does my kitchen faucet's handle get hot while not in use?

Tags: kitchens

My kitchen faucet is hot after it sits for a few minutes. The valve is off. How do I handle the problem, which just started?

Comment: That was less impressive than the pun in the last sentence. :P

Comment: Louis, we really need more information to help you. We're peering through the dark here. Please tell us something about your faucet and plumbing _in your question_. Thanks.

Comment: Their question might be more basic / start level, such as: 'what information can I provide to get help?'

Comment: Is it always hot, or only hot for several minutes after using it?

Comment: Is there any sort of circulation system in place that keeps hot water circulating through the pipes even when not in use?  Some houses have this if it's a long way from the hot water heater to the faucets to help reduce the time it takes for hot water to get to the fixtures.

Comment: That's the first thing I thought of too. The recirculating hot water pipes are below your faucet, so the heat in those pipes rises up to your faucet handle. The same would be true is you have a hot waster heater directly below the faucet.

Comment: @JRaef heat in general does not rise. Hot air rises in relation to cold air, but not water. Cold water actually gets less dense, which is why ice floats.

Comment: @dandavis - a little knowledge is a dangerous thing. The maximum density of water is at about 39.16°F / 3.98°C - so ice floats, yes. Ice is actually less dense than water at freezing temperatures, which makes it float more. But water warmer than 39.16F also rises, and water at "hot" temperatures is much less dense than water near freezing.

Comment: @Ecnerwal true, but there's not much convection in a pipe anyway. The end of the pipe also sufferers the most losses. If convection (in water) could transport heat effectively, we wouldn't need a circulation pump to get hot water from a basement furnace to a 2nd floor radiator. I actually agree with JRaef's statement, except for the word "rises"; it's far more conduction than convection he refers to. My physics teacher was irked by "heat rises" and it must be contagious.

Answer (score 1):

Hot plumbing fixtures can mean an electrical problem.  There's enough leakage current to make something warm but not enough to trip a circuit breaker.  The fixture is close enough to ground potential to not give someone a shock.  One way to test for this is to cut power at the circuit breaker to any circuit that is near the kitchen plumbing.  If this keeps the faucet from warming up then keep the circuit off and call an electrician.